# View make with multiple parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am working with laravel 4 and I have a page with a form where I edit a store. I send this data to a controller and validate the fields. In case something is wrong I return to the edit page and I am trying to send a message and the object. But something is not working because I can't get the message. I get only the object.

This is how I return the view:

```
if($validator->fails()) {
        return View::make('admin.editstore')->with('fail', 'Wrong input!!!')->with('store', $store);
    }
```

And this is how I get the message:

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success"> {{ Session::get('success') }} </div> 
@elseif (Session::has('fail'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger"> {{ Session::get('fail') }} </div>
@endif
```

In case something goes wrong I have access to the object in the edit page. But I can't access the message. Does anyone know what is the problem ? I'm out of ideas ..

PS: The part with getting the message on the page should be ok because I use it on other pages and it's working. I think the problem is on returning the view with multiple data, but I'm not sure how to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing multiple parameters by calling `->with()` multiple times is okay.  There is no issue there.

However, it doesn't look like your view is trying to access the `$fail` parameter passed to it.  Your view is looking for the fail message in the Session.  You either need to change the view to look at the `$fail` parameter passed to it, or you need to change the controller to put the `$fail` data in the Session rather than passing it to the view.

---

Also, I'm not sure if you are meaning to just make the edit view where you have, or if you actually wanted to redirect back to the edit view.  If you are using a resourceful route/controller, you tend to have something like this (only edit/update actions shown):

```
class StoreController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $store = Store::find($id);

        return View::make('admin.editstore')->with('store', $store);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        $rules = Store::$rules; // or wherever your rules are
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            // flash your fail message and redirect back to the edit form
            // with the input and the validator error messages
            Session::flash('fail', 'Invalid!');
            return Redirect::action('StoreController@edit', array($id))
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validator->messages());
        } else {
            // flash your success message and redirect to wherever you'd
            // like to go on success
            Session::flash('success', 'Valid!');
            return Redirect::action('StoreController@index');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, now I understand what was the problem and how it should be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just use [compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) and pass the variables that way. Then you can access those variables in your template via `$fail` and `$store`.

```
if($validator->fails()) {
    $fail = 'Wrong input!!!';
    return View::make('admin.editstore', compact('fail', 'store'));
}
```

Comment: this is not really working and i am confused because I can access `$store` variable but can't access `$fail` variable. I get an undefined variable exception..

Answer (score 1):

You can do smthing like:

```
$data = array(
         'fail'  => 'Wrong input!!!',
         'store' => $store
         );
return View::make('admin.editstore')->with($data);
```